# How to save a list of json data that i get from an API to a class property using fetch

Tags: json, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to call a localhost API that i created in my react app class. This API will return a list of json data, i'm trying to save these results in a property

I don't know much about Reacjs. What i have tried so far is to create a method that will call the API and return the data, the i call this method in my class and save the results in a property.
The type of this method is Promise since the results that i'm expectibng are a list of data :

```
let items: any[];
function getIncidentsFromApiAsync(): Promise<any[]>{
  return fetch('http://localhost:3978/calling')
.then((response) => response.json())
}
export class App extends React.Component<{}, IDetailsListCustomColumnsExampleState> {
  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);
    getIncidentsFromApiAsync().then(json => items = json);
  }
}
```

I haven't been able to see the results since items is always undefined after calling getIncidentsFromApiAsync() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle this in React using `State` and lifecycle method `componentDidMount` that gets called when the component is ready:

```
function getIncidentsFromApiAsync(): Promise<any[]>{
  return fetch('http://localhost:3978/calling').then(
      (response) => response.json()
  );
}

export class App extends React.Component<{}, IDetailsListCustomColumnsExampleState> {
    constructor(props: {}) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            items: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        getIncidentsFromApiAsync().then(json => this.setState({ items: json });
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.items.length) {
            const itemsList = this.state.items.map((item) => <li key={item}>{item}</li>);
            return (
                <div>
                    <ul>{itemsList}</ul>
                </div>
            );
        }

        return <div>List is not available</div>;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. After a small issue with CORS in my server it worked !